# How to create javascript code for Jump menu with active class and smooth scroll

Tags: javascript

In menu list, when I want to click on particular menu  it scrolls  (smoothly) to a specific section on the page. I have implemented in jquery but I don't know how to implement in javascript.
Please help me to convert this jquery code into javascript

```
$(".menu-1").click(function() {
       $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
           scrollTop: $("#section-1").offset().top
       }, 500);
   });
```

I have implement jquery code into javascript code just like that

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-1")
      for(var i =0; i< el.length;i++){
         el[i].addEventListener("click",scrollMenuHome)
      }
      function scrollMenuHome(){ 
         document.getElementById('section-1').scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
         });

      }
```

but that code not proper worked

Comment: Hi @Nikita! where exactly did you get stuck? what have you tried and didn't succeed? People will be more reluctant to help if you tell them what you need help with exactly instead of asking for a complete solution.

Comment: Please update the question and don't post code in the comments.